# Sockets - Receiving/sending message (php)

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to learn how to use sockets. 
However I have a problem when it comes to receives (or sending maybe) the message.

Here's the code I'm using to send messages:

```
    <?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    $msg = "Ping !";
    $len = strlen($msg);

    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '127.0.0.1', "3306");
    echo "Message sent!<br />";
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

The code I'm using to receive messages and display them:

```
    <?php
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    $adresse = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = "3306"; 

    echo("Connection... <br>");
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $adresse, $port) or die("impossible to connect! <br>");

    echo("Result: ".$result."<br>");

    while($out = socket_read($socket, 2048))
        echo $out;
    socket_close($socket);
    echo("<br />Socket closed!<br>"); 
?>
```

And that's what I'm receiving:

```
Connection...
```

``` Result: 1
N 5.6.12-log,HfIyF3hÿ÷€6r_aM;~-``}sImysql_native_passwordSocket closed! ```

I don't get why this is happening.
Thanks for your help! ;)

Comment: try to check the availibility of the port 3306 before starting your code (use nmap for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like if you have already a MySQL server started in your host in the port 3306, try to stop it and retry again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried to stop my Wamp and retry it but it is the same.
Oddly, I still receive a message even when I'm not launching the page to send a message. :/

Comment: did you check the port 3306 before starting your code ?

Comment: I checked with netstat command (netstat -a) the port I was listening on and it turns out that the port 3306 is in "Listening" state. I don't know if that's enough?

Comment: that's it ! you have to stop the proccess that use this port before your test. you can find it's PID using   `netstat -ao` which will add a PID column to the result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I checked and I saw that the PID correspond to wampmysqld (I'm using wamp to do my tests :/).

Comment: go to wamp icon -> MySQL -> service -> stop it

Comment: By doing so, I can't use my script anymore since I'm using wamp to make my tests :/

Comment: you will just stop MySQL service (tadabase service) but PHP and Apache are still in starting mode and you can use them.

Comment: That's weird then because I tried and here's the message I got :
"Warning: socket_connect(): in C:\wamp\www\search\sockets.php on line 13", namely this line :

"$result = socket_connect($socket, $adresse, $port) or die("impossible de se connecter à la socket <br>");"

Comment: may be it's due to the incoherence between Client and server protocol, you are using UDP in client (used flag SOL_UDP)  and TCP in server (used flag SOL_TCP)

Comment: first thing try a very simple code that send one char in the simplest way then improve it

Comment: In fact, this message appears even before I send anything. I'm just launching the page to receive messages and this warning message appears just like it doesn't know socket_connect(). And when I relaunch MySQL service, it works just fine. :/

Comment: Why using 3306 , change it to avoid those kinds of concurrency problem